# Whenever I type some wrong command, my terminal tries to run that command in the background

Tags: bash, shell, terminal, background-process

Something strange started happening to my terminal. Whenever I type some wrong command it tries to run that command in the background.

```
hegeek@colinux: ~# l   
[9]+  Stopped   l  
thegeek@colinux: ~# fdsl  

[10]+  Stopped                 fdsl
```

What could be the issue?

---

EDIT:

After restarting the system the issue is solved. But I am still curious what caused this issue. I think it has to do something with `command_not_found_handle` shell function. While trying to find the command, it was doing something weird.

Comment: What output do you get from the `alias` command?

Comment: just one "alias ls='ls --color=auto'". Its an new colinux installation.

Comment: Does saying `/bin/sh -l` fix it?  If not, what about switching to another shell, like `tcsh -l`?

Comment: this is a weird problem +1 because I've no clue.

Comment: @Warren Young: After restarting ubuntu this problem solved. But I dont know what caused it.

Answer (score 6):

That sounds like [the command-not-found hook](https://web.archive.org/web/20100603061958/http://www.workswithu.com/2009/08/17/enhanced-command-not-found-hook-in-ubuntu-910) was acting up for some reason. I've had problems with it before, but never could figure out how to fix it :-/.